# Split nested list based on unique value

Tags: python, split

I have got a list with vector points which I would like to split based on the second value of the nested list, the y position. So, `points[0][1]`. 
The example list contains two unique y heights: `920` and `940`. But a list could have easily 10 unique y heights.

```
points = [(418, 920), (558, 920), (726, 920), (858, 920), (906, 920), (1042, 920), (418, 940), (558, 940), (734, 940), (865, 940), (899, 940), (1034, 940)]

# Desired result:
newPoints = [ [ [x,920], [x,920]  ], [ [x,940], [x,940] ] ]
```

Comment: I think it is not clear what your desired result should be, please specify it.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann, I understand. But Maarten gave me the desirable solution.

Comment: If you invest the time to make your question more readable, then others, who have the same problem and find your questions, benefit more from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where a `collections .defaultdict` comes in:

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_points = defaultdict(list)
for point in points:
    new_points[point[1]].append(point)
```

> ```
> defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
> 920: [(418, 920), (558, 920), (726, 920), (858, 920), (906, 920), (1042, 920)], 
> 940: [(418, 940), (558, 940), (734, 940), (865, 940), (899, 940), (1034, 940)]
> })
> ```

If you need the lists, you can do `new_points.values()` or `list(new_points.values())`

> ```
> [[(418, 920), (558, 920), (726, 920), (858, 920), (906, 920), (1042, 920)],
>  [(418, 940), (558, 940), (734, 940), (865, 940), (899, 940), (1034, 940)]]
> ```

Comment: Thanks! @Maarten, for now, since I'm still learning Pyhton, I'll stick to the for me understandable list solution.

Answer (score 0):

I created a dictionary of y-values to its list of  x values, then iterated through the y-values, creating a sublist for each one, and iterated through the x-values, create a sublist for each of those.

```
points = [(418, 920), (558, 920), (726, 920), (858, 920), (906, 920), (1042, 920), (418, 940), (558, 940), (734, 940), (865, 940), (899, 940), (1034, 940)]

y_dict = dict()

for point in points:
    x = point[0]
    y = point[1]
    if y in y_dict.keys():
        #already found this y
        y_dict[y].append(x)
    else:
        #haven't found this y
        y_dict[y] = [x]

newPoints = []

for y in y_dict.keys():
    sublist = []
    for x in y_dict[y]:
        sublist.append([x, y])
    newPoints.append(sublist)

print(newPoints)
```

Then the result is:

```
[[[418, 920], [558, 920], [726, 920], [858, 920], [906, 920], [1042, 920]], [[418, 940], [558, 940], [734, 940], [865, 940], [899, 940], [1034, 940]]]
```

Comment: what a huge algorithm for something that can be easily solved by a builtin